# MSSQL comparing 2 columns issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I have two tables:
Customers info, like id,customerName,address etc.. and RecipientOfGoods - customerId, address.
The addresses from both tables differ, the address in customer table is by registration and the address in second table is delivery address. I need to add in the first table the recipient of goods address in order to compare the two type of addresses.

```
use dwh01
SELECT distinct
       cus.[BranchId]
      ,cus.[CustomerId]
      ,cus.[CustomerName]
      ,cus.[Street] as StreetByReg
      ,del.Street as StreetForDelivery
      ,cus.[Postalcode] as PKByReg
      ,del.Postalcode as PKForDelivery
      ,cus.[City] as CityByReg
      ,del.City as CityForDelivery
      ,cus.[PhoneNumber]
      ,cus.[EMail]
      ,cus.[IsActive]
      ,cus.[LastChangeDate]
  FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] cus 
 join live.DimRecipientOfGoods del on del.RecipientOfGoodsid = cus.Customerid
 where cus.BranchId in('1080','1081') and ltrim(cus.CustomerId) = '99060'
```

Thats my query, and i do get the needed result, but i also get on second row the same info but in the columns for address from the second table i get the address from first table. The question is how to remove that useless second row appearing and why it happens like this?

[image: Screenshot of query and result. First row is what i need, second row is useless.]

Comment: Can you also provide us with the data you used to get this result. My guess is that there simply are more than one row from the joined table, but I need to see that data to be sure

Comment: Looks like you have multiple delivery rows for a customer

Comment: I guess the answer is: what do you want it to show, given that `DimRecipientOfGoods` has duplicate rows? What should it do instead? Aggregation? Top 1 per group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN excluding equal rows to get only customers with new addresses.

```
SELECT distinct
       cus.[BranchId]
      ,cus.[CustomerId]
      ,cus.[CustomerName]
      ,cus.[Street] as StreetByReg
      ,del.Street as StreetForDelivery
      ,cus.[Postalcode] as PKByReg
      ,del.Postalcode as PKForDelivery
      ,cus.[City] as CityByReg
      ,del.City as CityForDelivery
      ,cus.[PhoneNumber]
      ,cus.[EMail]
      ,cus.[IsActive]
      ,cus.[LastChangeDate]
  FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] cus 
  JOIN live.DimRecipientOfGoods del ON del.RecipientOfGoodsid = cus.Customerid 
     AND (cus.[Street] <> del.[Street] OR cus.[Postalcode] <> del.[Postalcode] OR cus.[City] <> del.[City]) 
  WHERE cus.BranchId in('1080','1081') and ltrim(cus.CustomerId) = '99060'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inner join please use left join to get all the customer information from DimCustomer but additional address information from DimRecipientOfGoods only.

Since there are two separate address information in second table and one is exact match from first table. You can have one address information from first table and
in second table you can ignore that address by comparing two addresses. But I am not sure whether this condition will be same for all the customers. You can choose inner join over left join if you want to remove those customers who have
no records in DimRecipientOfGoods table.

```
 use dwh01
    SELECT Distinct
           cus.[BranchId]
          ,cus.[CustomerId]
          ,cus.[CustomerName]
          ,cus.[Street] as StreetByReg
          ,del.Street as StreetForDelivery
          ,cus.[Postalcode] as PKByReg
          ,del.Postalcode as PKForDelivery
          ,cus.[City] as CityByReg
          ,del.City as CityForDelivery
          ,cus.[PhoneNumber]
          ,cus.[EMail]
          ,cus.[IsActive]
          ,cus.[LastChangeDate]
      FROM [dwh01].[live].[DimCustomer] cus 
     Left join live.DimRecipientOfGoods del on del.RecipientOfGoodsid = cus.Customerid
 AND (cus.Street <> del.Street OR cus.Postalcode <> del.Postalcode OR cus.City <> del.City) 
     where cus.BranchId in('1080','1081') and ltrim(cus.CustomerId) = '99060'
```

Comment: distinct won't work, look at his picture, some columns have different values in the duplicate rows

Comment: Thats the same, gives same result.

Comment: @svetozarslavkov Do you have duplicate entry in DimCustomer table ? Please share sample data.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur No i dont have duplicate data in any of the 2 tables, we have 2 branched 1080 and 1081, and 1 customer is created in both branches in some cases, but with different ID's.

Comment: @svetozarslavkov You have duplicate value in pkfordelivery and cityfordelivery field. You can either use max() or min() on them or you can void those field.

Comment: Without seeing the data that produced this result, it is impossible for anyone to tell where the duplicate rows come from. Please provide us with this data, help us help you

Comment: I found out that i have duplicate rows from recipient of goods table, its same ID but 2 different recipient of goods keys. How do i make it show only 1? The duplicate rows are because of the 2 branched, 1 row is for 1080 and second is for 1081.